# How to tell which password requirements aren't met by a new password in Windows?

Tags: windows, passwords

When I try to update my password on Windows 10, I sometimes get the message

> The value provided for the new password doesn't meet the length, complexity or history requirements

Is there a way to find out which ones of the three were actually violated? If there's a way to display the exact length and complexity requirements, that would be even better.

Comment: Is the machine on a domain? If so, the requirements will be specified in AD. A Windows client machine won't be able to pull through those settings, afaik.

Comment: You can try the powershell command `Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -Current LoggedOnUser` . It will give you some information like Minimum password length, password history requirement, and if complexity requirement is enabled.

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, it is on a domain. I would consider a non-domain answer helpful too.

Comment: @S.Brottes Are you running that on a client machine? When I run that I get a term not recognised error.

Comment: Ask you IT department, we cannot help with domain controlled environments, it is off topic here at SU

Comment: @Moab And yet I got an answer right here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `net accounts /domain` to get your current password policy.

Keep in mind, if the minimum amount of days is set to 1 or bigger, you cannot change the password twice on one day. So, for example, you have trouble logging in, the IT department resets your password to something temporary, that does count as a password change, so you cannot change your password again to something you want for that day.

Also, often its not told, but the password cannot contain part of your first or last name, nor your username, even if you meet all the other criteria.